# prolog permutation(?L, ?L1)

Tags: prolog, permutation

I am trying to create a permute(?L, ?L1) predicate.

So that when I execute:

```
      permute([1,2], X).
      X = [1,2] ;
      X = [2,1]; 

      permute(X, [1,2]).
      X = [1,2]
      X = [2,1]
```

If you run the built-in function:

```
      permutation(X, [1,2]).
```

The stack overflows.

I have tried codes like:

```
permute1([], []).
permute1([X|Rest], L) :-
    permute1(Rest, L1),
    select(X, L, L1).

 permute2([], []).
 permute2(L, [P | P1]) :-
     select(P, L, L1),
     permute2(L1, P1).

 generator(L, L1):-
      findall(X,permutation(L,X),L1).
```

but none work. 
I appreciate the help beforehand.

Comment: On GNU Prolog, try `permutation([1,2],X).` instead of `permutation(X,[1,2]).`

Comment: As I said: I desire to be able to permute with either variable. So I want to be able to permute using permutation([1,2],X). and permutation(X,[1,2]). Both variables should be unbound.

Comment: The answer you accepted is incorrect....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have a wrapper around `permutation`:

```
permute(X, L) :-
    ( nonvar(L) ->
        permutation(X, L)
    ;
        permutation(L, X)
    ).
```

Comment: @Alessandroempire: either `permute([_|_],[])` or `permute([],[_|_])` loops.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `permutation/2` is that it does not terminate as good as it could. So, first, we need to understand what we can expect from a Prolog predicate's termination properties. Note that we can do these considerations without looking at the concrete definition!

### Set of solutions

First, start to consider what set of solutions queries possess. If that set is finite, then Prolog `might` terminate. If it is infinite, and we would have to enumerate all solutions, then we cannot expect Prolog to terminate.  In your example, consider

- `permute(L,[])`. Here, the set is finite, it would therefore be nice, if the predicate would terminate.
- `permute([X],L)`. Here, the set is infinite.

But are we really interested in seeing all solutions? Like `X = 1, L = [1]` and many, many more? In fact, `X` might be any term, so we might relax (or generalize) what we expect from Prolog: Instead of concrete solutions, we might be happy with **answer substitutions** that also contain variables. In fact, `L = [X]` describes all infinitely many solutions with a single answer substitution.

### Answers

In case the set of solutions is infinite, we will try to figure out if that set can be described with finitely many answers. However, if only infinitely many answers are able to represent the set of solutions, a query **must not** terminate. Consider:
`permute([a,b|L],[c,d|M]).`  Here, we need infinitely many answers. Like
`L = [c,d], M = [a,b] ; L = [c,d,X1], M = [a,b,X1]` etc. If the predicate would terminate in such a situation, some solutions would be left out.

So after these considerations we now know where a predicate **might** terminate, and where it **must** loop. In our case, `permute/2` must loop iff both arguments are **partial lists**.

To put it in another direction, the predicate (ideally) terminates, if the length of one of the lists is known.

Note that for `permute/2`, both lists are of same length, thus:

```
same_length([], []).
same_length([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :-
   same_length(Xs, Ys).

permute(Xs, Ys) :-
   same_length(Xs, Ys),  % redundant goal
   permutation(Xs, Ys).
```

Instead of `same_length/2` you might write `maplist(\_^_^true,Xs, Ys)` using [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl).

Comment: In GNU Prolog, `permute(L, L), L=[_].` will run infinitely after succeeding once.

Comment: @lurker: Of course, it **has to**, since `permute(L, L)` alone needs infinitely many answers

Comment: @lurker: Maybe to clarify:  `permute(L,L), L = [_]` viewed as one goal certainly has a infinite set of solutions that can be represented compactly - and so ideally it would not loop. But the `','` here is just Prolog's control construct...

Comment: s(X): Is there a particular reason why `same_length/2` isn't part of the Prolog prologue?

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to constrain the length of the lists to be the same (assuming at least one list is instantiated):

```
permute(L, P) :-
    length(L, N),
    length(P, N), !,
    permutation(L, P).
```

Comment: You are not constraining: `permute([_|_],[])` loops.

Comment: Oh ... thanks @false. It constrains but just not enough. ;) I like your `same_length/2` solution better (+1).

Comment: "constrains not enough": sometimes too much: `permute(L,L),L=[_].` should succeed, but it fails.